# select2 not calling ajax action in my MVC application

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-select2

I am using select2 in my ASP.NET MVC application for dropdown lists.

Following are the version details:
Select2 - 4.0.1-rc.1
jQuery - 2.1.0
BootStrap - 3.1.1
ASP.NET MVC 5

I have imported select2.full.js script file in the application.

Following is the placeholder for select2 control in my MVC razor view:

```
<input id="categoryLevelId" type="hidden" value="@Model.CategoryLevelId" class="form-control" />
```

Following is the javascript to attach select2 with this input element:

```
$(function () {
        $('#categoryLevelId').select2(
        {
            placeholder: 'Select Category',
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            allowClear: true,
            formatResult: formatResult,
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action(MVC.Lookup.ActionNames.GetCategoriesLookupList, MVC.Lookup.Name)',
                dateType: "json",
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {
                        searchTerm: term
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    };
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

When I run the application the "categoryLevelId" control is correctly showing as DropDown (which does prove that the select2 library is loaded and attached to the control), however, the Action is not getting called and so the dropdown doesn't show any data for selection.

I have used this control without any issues in the past in MVC projects, but that was for older versions of select2. I am not sure, if this has something to do with using bootstrap and select2 together at the same place, or there is some issue with my implementation.

Anyone else facing the same issues with select2? Any help on this will be much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: how does the rendered `url` look?

Comment: the rendered url looks like - "http://localhost:1000/mywebsite/Lookup/GetCategoriesLookupList" which I could see by putting the javascript alert. The URL looks correct and the action is HttpGet which returns Json (with AllowGet as its request behavior)